Pair Pop Up Come Twice Android Bluetooth
In Android 11, 12, 13 and android 14 versions, the following issue is observed: When a bond is created with a peripheral, and I remove the bond from the device settings, then try to pair again, the pairing popup appears twice. Has anyone encountered this issue, or does anyone have any input on this?

This is a known bug/issue in the Android OS. The issue seems to stem from how Android handles bonding requests when they originate from the peripheral side.
When a BLE peripheral (especially those with Nordic chips) initiates bonding, Android's system-level Bluetooth stack often triggers the pairing dialog twice. This can lead to failed connections or a confusing user experience.
NB: the workaround is to initiate bonding from the app using createBond() (if you have control over the peripheral firmware) but there is no equivalent method for this in iOS.

The issue is not observed in Android 10, but it is happening from Android 11 onwards. Gabeldorsche is a new Bluetooth stack that's been in development since Android 11. Any in-depth details on what might be causing this issue would be helpful.

Is there any other work around other than createBond() from phone?

Another (undocumented) hack that seems to be working is to make a quick discovery on the BLE adapter right after gaining the BLE scanning permissions, on all non-Samsung devices:
private suspend fun startPairingPopupHack(adapter: BluetoothAdapter) {
    val manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER
    if (manufacturer != "samsung") {
        adapter.startDiscovery()
        delay(1000)
        adapter.cancelDiscovery()
    }
}

This way the device only prompts the system dialog for pairing avoiding the tedious double notification.


This happens when you try to connect without pairing.
You should call  device.connectGatt() if
model.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED

